# saving search key words in my web site

Tags: javascript, html, google-search

I am developing a web site in it I am using Google search bar, code I used

```
<form  id="form_body" method="get" action="http://www.google.com /search">
    <p>Google Search<input type="text" name="q"/>
    <input type="submit" value="Search"/></p>
</form>
```

Now the problem is I want the key words entered for search to be saved I tried using this code

```
<form  id="form_body" method="get" action="http://www.google.com/search">
    <p>Google Search<input type="text" name="q"/>
    <input type="button" onclick="save1()" value="Search"/></p>
</form>
```

where `save1` is my javascript function which does not work(not at all working)

Comment: For what purpose are you trying to save the search keywords? For the user to reuse or to be stored in a database for some other use? Also, what does your save1() function currently look like?

Comment: Also why have you changed submit to button?

Comment: sbeliv01: just to save in database I was using this. and I was like planing to write a ajax function using my "save1" function but I didnot I stuck at this point and I thought changing it to button is more convenient while using javascript

Comment: So you have a [Form](http://api.jquery.com/submit/). You want to use [AJAX](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/). Why you don't use [jQuery](http://jquery.com/)?

Comment: I realy do not have any clue about JQUERY i am interested in ajax using javascript and php

Comment: Please pay attention to the edits that were made to your question. The formatting and grammar needed serious attention.

Answer (score 2):

When you hook the `click` event of a submit button in a form, it will not fire/stop firing when the page unloads.  Instead, hook the `submit` event to ensure your code fires *before* the page is ever submitted.

```
<form  id="form_body" method="get" action="http://www.google.com/search" onsubmit="return save1();">               
<p>Google Search<input type="text" name="q"/>
<input type="submit" value="Search"/></p>
```

Answer (score 0):

Create an ajax call on the submit of the button that pulls in the text input value and then sends it to a php file to store the value in a database.